# C# - Network flooding

Tags: unity, networking, mmo

I just created a simple MMO in unity3d, then me and my friends test it via LAN and the result is very smooth. But when I hosted it in public (100ms ping) the server became unresponsive and causes random disconnection.

Host Setup 
- 1gbps 
- 32gb ram 
- 256 ssd 
- off firewall

Server Setup 
- max of 100 players 
- every 100ms update 
- no other updates, just only X and Y location of player by index 
- c# sockets w/ async

Server Flow 
- when 100ms tick reaches, server sends position of player base on index in a loop.

ex.

```
if (gtick >= 0.1f) {
    for (x < maxPlayers; x++) {

        // check ifs
        //couples of ifs here...

        // send
        sendToWorld(x ... player[x].posX ... player[x].posY);
    }

    // somewhere, gtick = 0, then counts up again...

}
```

then the result is delay, unresponsive, and random disconnection.
maybe it flooding itself, I don't know. but when we test it locally (10+ players), it is very smooth and no problem at all.

My question is, How can I update all players every 0.1 without server flooding itself?